# How can I have separate debug and release versions of gradle project that pull in different versions of the same class?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build

I have two versions of the same Java class (same name / methods). Since it's Java, both .java files have the same name. I want to configure gradle in such a way that I can build a "debug" version of my application that pulls in one of these files, and a "production" version of my application that pulls in the other one. How would I go about doing this?

This class has only static methods. I don't ever want to make an instance of this class. I additionally don't want to add the overhead of an `if` statement in each of the methods on this class to check which version I'm in.

Comment: Classloader shenanigans.  Also, you can't load and resolve both versions at the same time, at least not how you'd probably like to.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. Sounds like this maybe isn't the right way to go about this then. Maybe I could pull out a Java interface that both of these classes meet, and then somehow at Gradle build time set some flag that could be read at Java runtime to choose which class to instantiate / use?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "load and resolve both versions at the same time"?

Comment: I don't know how big the differences are between the 2 versions but maybe use a local.properties to define different values for some variable.

Comment: The differences are that one version has a lot of expensive logic to check that values passed to it look right. It's helpful for debugging, but I don't want it to happen in production.

Comment: you can have just 1 version of your file and check from your local.properties `if(isDebugmode){------do heavy logic-------}`

Comment: I don't want to add that overhead to the method. This is a function that gets called all the time and has to be as fast as possible. See edits.

Answer (score 4):

Following @JFabianMeier's answer you could use 4 projects:

1. with the production version class
2. with the debug version class
3. with code that uses either of the two, parameterized according to [Migrating Maven profiles ...](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html#migmvn:profiles_and_properties) → *Example 6. Mimicking the behavior of Maven profiles in Gradle*. (I'm also a Maven guy and therefore can't tell you exactly how to do it in Gradle.)
4. a [multi](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)-[project](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/) with 1./2./3. as [sub](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:subproject_configuration)[-][projects](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/#configure_from_above) for building all of them in one go, maybe parameterized to build just 1.+ 3. or 2.+ 3.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried creating production and debug source directories/sets? According to the docs you can use multiple directories when specifying source directories in your source set. Try dropping the different versions of your class in their respective production/debug source directories.

I haven't tested myself (not sure about the syntax), but this is based on the Gradle's [Java compilation documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html).

```
sourceSets {
    // Could also name this production
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs ['src/main/java', 'src/prod/java']
        }
    }
    debug {
        java {
            srcDirs ['src/main/java', 'src/debug/java']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

- Put the class into a separate project (so generate a separate jar from it)
- Then you can have two different jars, for production and debugging
- Then you can pull either one or the other jar in gradle depending on a parameter.

Alternatively, you could look into template engines like Velocity which allow you to generate source code during the build depending on variables and then compile it.

Comment: Would two separate projects necessitate compiling all of the code twice? Ideally, I'd only have to compile all of the shared files once. 

Also, when you say "separate project", is a "project" something defined in Gradle?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit imprecise because I am a Maven guy. In Maven, you could have a multi-module project that contains of several modules (sub projects) that each generate an artifact. You can then build everything in one go. I guess gradle offers your similar features.

Comment: @JFabianMeier It's called _[multi](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html)-[project](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/)_ with _[sub](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:subproject_configuration)\[-][projects](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/#configure_from_above)_ in Gradle.

Comment: @GeroldBroser Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Android has a neat feature called Product Flavors. It lets you swap classes at compile time effortlessly and keep your project clean.

This post is very good to get a taste of it: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/12/leveraging-product-flavors-in-android.html

And here is the full documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors

Comment: This seems like almost exactly what I had in mind. Is this Android only though?

Comment: I believe so! My bad! I thought your question was on Android!